# Counting integer digits

Tags: java, math, integer

I'm trying to count the digits of an integer with java, it supposed to give 4 but instead I get 1 .
I don't know if I did something wrong, if someone could help.
Here's the code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 4781, i = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            n %= 10;
            n /= 10;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Comment: What do you think `n %= 10` does here?

Comment: Add `System.out.println(n);` inside your while loop to find what goes wrong.

Comment: You overwrite n with %10 there and divide that result by 10.
Also the loop check on exactly 0 is a bit too optimistic here.
You could just divide by 10 and check `while (n <= 0)`.

Answer (score 4):

The `n %= 10` is unnecessary and in fact the source of the problem here. If you remove it, the code will work.

Usually when you do these kinds of "do something for each digit" you use `% 10` to find the current digit a little bit like this:

```
int digit = n % 10;
System.out.println("The current digit is " + digit);
```

But in your case you don't actually care what the digits are, you only care how many there are, so there's no need to do `% 10` at all.

And the way you did it you overwrote `n` (which is supposed to hold the current state of the number) with the current digit and *then* divided by 10. So no matter what the first digit is, this will never return a number bigger than 1.